# How to load API data video url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dompurify

I have installed dompurify react js library and loaded all the contended as it is from API but API youtube URL video failed to load but can be seen in API.

**API:**

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "shahiraja",
    "title": "text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit l text below as a natural lead-in to ad",
    "image": "/media/resources/Screenshot_from_2021-09-14_19-13-25.png",
    "created_at": "2022-01-03T08:07:44.451476Z",
    "body": "<p><iframe frameborder=\"0\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/LNkdmyHp5Co\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" class=\"note-video-clip\"></iframe><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNkdmyHp5Co\"></a><br></p>",
    "category": 1
}
```

**Code:**

```
<div
    class="col-md-10"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(body.body) }}
></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `sanitize` is a bit too opinionated for your needs out-of-the-box, the `iframe` is stripped out. You can pass a configuration and allow the `iframe` tag.

```
<div
  className="col-md-10"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: sanitize(body.body, { ADD_TAGS: ["iframe"] })
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit how-to-load-api-data-video-url-in-react-js]

[image]

Comment: It worked thanks, can i have a link to read more about it

Comment: @AMRITSHAHI There's nothing quite like [official documentation](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#can-i-configure-dompurify)  , it just takes a minute to grok from all the examples. For example, I had initially said to use the `ALLOWED_TAGS` but this excluded ***all other tags***, so had to find what was less restrictive. Turns out we just wanted only to add `iframe` to the already preset list of accepted tags.

Answer (score 0):

If from API you are getting the data as an HTML code then its better to go with

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Otherwise if you get the URL of file then simply use the video tag.

```
<video
    autoPlay
    playsInline
    muted
    src={src}
    onLoadedData={onLoadedData}
    style={{ opacity: isVideoLoaded ? 1 : 0 }}
  />
```